# JavaScript get data-* of element

Tags: javascript

I have this element:

```
<input id="ider" data-orderid="100" type="text" class="form-control" value="ABCDEF">
```

I want to take `data-orderid` of input:

```
orderId = document.getElementById("ider").data-orderid;
```

At execution at get this error: `orderid is not defined`

If I execute `$(ider)` in console of Chrome I can find `orderid` in list of attributes

[image]

What I do wrong?

Comment: You can use `.getAttribute` to pull this off!  `document.getElementById("ider").getAttribute('data-orderid');` https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/getAttribute

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are nearly there!
Check out the correct syntax:

```
string = element.dataset.camelCasedName;
element.dataset.camelCasedName = string;

string = element.dataset[camelCasedName];
element.dataset[camelCasedName] = string;
```

In your case it would be:

```
orderId = document.getElementById("ider").dataset.orderid;
```

or

```
orderId = document.getElementById("ider").dataset['orderid'];
```

Source: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/dataset

Answer (score 1):

Did you try?:

```
let elem = document.getElementById('ider');
```

and

```
elem.getAttribute('data-orderid');
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use getAttribute method

```
console.log(document.getElementById("ider").getAttribute('data-orderid'));
```

```js
console.log(document.getElementById("ider").getAttribute('data-orderid'));
```

```html
<input id="ider" data-orderid="100" type="text" class="form-control" value="ABCDEF">
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`dataset`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/HTML/Howto/Use_data_attributes) as well as [`getAttribute`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/getAttribute) to access `data-orderid`.

```js
console.log(document.getElementById("ider").dataset.orderid);
console.log(document.getElementById("ider").getAttribute('data-orderid'));
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper {max-height: 100% !important; top: 0;}
```

```html
<input id="ider" data-orderid="100" type="text" class="form-control" value="ABCDEF">
```